# Scheme: what wrong with that code?

Tags: scheme

I wrote this code to remove duplicate and it is work. But when i add the option for the equal function there are problems. what can i do??
thank you!!

```
(define (remove-dups ls eq)
  (if (null? ls) '()
      (cons (car ls) (remove-dups (deepRemove (car ls) (cdr ls) eq)))))

(define (deepRemove n L eq)
  (if (null? L) '()
  (if (list? (car L))
      (cons (deepRemove n (car L) eq) (deepRemove n (cdr L) eq))
      (if (eq? n (car L))(deepRemove n (cdr L) eq)
          (cons (car L)(deepRemove n (cdr L) eq))))))
```

Comment: What problems, what does/doesn't work as expected? Please be as explicit as possible when describing problems.

Comment: You do not call the predicate (`eq`) passed into `deepRemove` (the `if` uses the built-in `eq?`)

Comment: What i need to change? thank you

Comment: @ellacohen, is there a reason you removed the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two errors with your code. First, you're passing the wrong number of arguments to `remove-dups`. Second, you're not actually using the `eq` parameter in `deepRemove`. Also, you should use `cond` instead of nesting `if`s, but that's more a matter of style. Try this:

```
(define (remove-dups ls eq)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (cons (car ls)
            (remove-dups (deepRemove (car ls) (cdr ls) eq) eq)))) ; fixed

(define (deepRemove n L eq)
  (if (null? L)
      '()
      (if (list? (car L))
          (cons (deepRemove n (car L) eq)
                (deepRemove n (cdr L) eq))
          (if (eq n (car L)) ; fixed
              (deepRemove n (cdr L) eq)
              (cons (car L)
                    (deepRemove n (cdr L) eq))))))
```

The above will work as long as you pass an appropriate `eq` procedure that takes into consideration all the possible values that need to be compared, be careful with that.